# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object in Next.js app 13, next auth v4,

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

using next.js app version 13.4.2 , next-auth: 4.22.1, I am working next.js and next auth and making signin and signout using googleProvider .when i tries to modify this code then comes another error . now I am getting this error Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

error

```
 error src\app\login\page.jsx (26:15) @ values
- error TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.values (<anonymous>)
    at SignIn (./src/app/login/page.jsx:27:26)
  24 |   return (
  25 |     <div>
> 26 |        {Object.values(providers).map(provider =>{
     |               ^
  27 |           <div key={provider.name}>
  28 |               <button>
  29 |                   Sign in with {provider.name}
```

app/components/provider.js

```
'use client'

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
 
const Provider = ({children, session}) =>{
    return <SessionProvider session={session}>{children}</SessionProvider>
}

export default Provider;
```

app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter"
import clientPromise from "../../../../../lib/mongodb"

const handler = NextAuth({
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    providers: [
            GoogleProvider({
              clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID ,
              clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
            }),
            // ...add more providers here
          ],
     
     pages: {
      signIn: "/login",
    },
     session:{
      strategy:"jwt"
     },
     secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
     callbacks:{
      jwt:async({token, user}) =>{
        user && (token.user = user)
        return token
      },
      sesssion: async({session, token}) =>{
        // const user  = token.user 
        // session.user = user
        // return session

        if (session?.user && token?.sub) {
            session.user.id = token.sub;
        }
        return session;
      }
     }
})


export {handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

app/login/pagejs

```
'use client';

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import {getProviders, signIn, useSession, getSession } from "next-auth/react";




export default function SignIn({providers}) {
  // const {data:sessionData, status} = useSession();
  // const router = useRouter();


  // if (status === 'loading') {
  //   return '';
  // }

  // console.log("session", sessionData);
  // console.log("Provider", providers);
  // if (sessionData) {
  //   router.push('/');
  // }

  return (
    <div>
       {Object.values(providers).map(provider =>{
          <div key={provider.name}>
              <button>
                  Sign in with {provider.name}
              </button>
          </div>
       })}
    </div>
  );
}



export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const providers = await getProviders();
  return {
    props: {providers},
  }
}
```